# Why does a real spectrum not have holes?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Apparently, if $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and the spectrum $\sigma(a) \subseteq \mathbb R$ then $\sigma (a)$ does not have holes.

I read this in Murphy and then tried to prove it since I didn't believe it. But I can't seem to prove it (even though -- since it's mentioned without proof -- it must be trivial).

Can someone please explain to me how to prove that a real spectrum is simply connected?

Edit

This is from page 41:

[image]

Comment: If $a$ is a non-trivial projection, then $\sigma(a) = \{0,1\}$, so I doubt this result ...

Comment: Every connected component of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is simply connected. Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ have no holes in the sense of "generating a nontrivial fundamental group". Is it possible that that is what was meant? (Since it is easy to give examples of disconnected real spectra.)

Comment: Can you give the concrete page in Murphy?

Comment: @martini I included the relevant part in the question.

Comment: Added something to my answer.

Comment: My guess is that they're talking about a hole in 2d. For example, if the spectrum consisted of the closed annulus $0 < r_{1} \le |\lambda| \le r_{2}$. Then the open disk of radius $r_{1}$ centered at the origin would be a hole. Maybe that's it? You couldn't have that type of hole when the spectrum is contained on the real line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement "a real spectrum is simply connected" is wrong. To give a concrete example, let $A = B(\mathbb C^2)$, where $\mathbb C^2$ carries the standard inner product. Let $$ a = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
Then $\sigma(a) = \{0,1\}$, which is not connected. Note that - in general - on $B(\mathbb C^n)$, the spectrum consists of at most $n$ points and is almost never connected.

---

As Murphy writes on page 11, proof of Thm. 1.2.8, by $\sigma_A(b)$ "having no holes", he means that $\mathbb C \setminus \sigma_A(b)$ is connected. But this is obviously true for bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your remark that clarification is needed.